# Qt4.8 : QWebView and HTTPS

Tags: https, qt4, qtwebkit

After having had a hell of a time to make SSL works on Qt with windows, most HTTPS website seem to be working. Untrusted certificate are now added when required and such, well everything is fine ... BUT I can't login on reuters.com for some weird reason.

Take a QWebView, add a bit of magic to handle ssl errors that shows up, go on reuters then click on sign in.
Then something weird occurs. First of all, it requested acceptance of untrusted certificates, which ain't that weird. But then, once that is done, nothing happens. QWebView waits and never send the loadFinished(bool) signal. More over the web page displayed doesn't change.

When I try to do this on Firefox or IE, it tells me that there is mixed content on the webpage. Could it be the problem?